# angular google maps weird issue with $event (very simple task)

Tags: angular

I've loaded google maps onto my angular project and i'm trying to attach a simple onmapclick event
like this :

```
<agm-map [disableDoubleClickZoom]='true' [latitude]='lat' [longitude]='lng' (mapClick)='clickedMap($event)'>
</agm-map>
```

my clickedMap function is the being called and then I simply want to console log $event to get the lat and lng of the clicked area :

```
 clickedMap(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
```

but instead i get in my console the following :
[console.log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S8lt.png)

I've been stuck on this for a few hours now and can't understand why it returns the letter C.
I also tried using the dbMapClick event and same issue - i get the letter D in my console.

Thanks

Comment: Which lib are you using? Is it angular-maps.com? Also, is the console.log(e) in line 31 of the map-vie component?

Comment: Yep the map loaded correctly all the other methods work correctly... the issue seems to be with just click events ... on double click it return the letter D and on regular click in returns the letter C

Comment: also i just tried to make a new testing project and same issue :/

Comment: can you try using double quotes on (mapClick)? Also are there any errors on the console where you started ng serve?